# How to arrange QCamera with other widgets in a layout?

Tags: c++, qt, qlayout, qtmultimedia

This is about arranging a multimedia object with widgets.
Following is what I have tried:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_QPushButton_calibration = new QPushButton("Calibrate", this);
    connect(m_QPushButton_calibration, SIGNAL (released()),this, SLOT (handleButton()));


    QList<QCameraInfo> l_QListQCameraInfo_available_cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();
    if (l_QListQCameraInfo_available_cameras.length() > 2)
    {
        m_QCamera_required_camera = new QCamera (l_QListQCameraInfo_available_cameras[1]);
    }

    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(m_QPushButton_calibration);
    layout->addWidget(m_QCamera_required_camera);

    this->setLayout(layout);
}
```

It results in :

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QHBoxLayout::addWidget(QCamera*&)'
     layout->addWidget(m_QCamera_required_camera);
                                                ^
```

How to arrange QCamera with other widgets in a layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QCamera itself is not a widget! But from [the qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcamera.html) we learn:

*"QCamera can be used with QCameraViewfinder for viewfinder display, QMediaRecorder for video recording and QCameraImageCapture for image taking."*

So I guess what you want might be a QCameraViewfinder:

```
QCameraViewfinder* cameraView = new QCameraViewfinder (this);

cameraView->setMediaObject (m_QCamera_required_camera);

layout->addWidget(cameraView);
```

Answer (score 1):

`QCamera` is not a widget, you should use a `QCameraViewfinder` (add multimediawidgets to .pro):

```
QCameraViewfinder *mCameraViewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder(this);
m_QCamera_required_camera->setViewfinder(mCameraViewfinder);

layout->addWidget(m_QPushButton_calibration);
layout->addWidget(mCameraViewfinder);
m_QCamera_required_camera->start();
```

[Complete code](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/Camera)